# sql query not working correctly

Tags: sql

```
USE [cms]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SpGetRelatedProducts]    Script Date: 10/10/2012 14:35:39 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[SpGetRelatedProducts](@pid int)
AS
DECLARE @subcate int;
select subcate_id as subcate from product where pid=@pid
SELECT *
FROM product
where product.subcate_id=@subcate




exec SpGetRelatedProducts 2
```

The above sql query is not working correctly as wanted.

I want the product details of only those products, that have subcatid=(subcatid of given pid).

There are 2 issues

1. only 1 output should appear instead of 2
2. 2nd output is not working correctly

Comment: Is the stored procedure in anyway relevant to the question?

Comment: What you need is `SELECT fieldName INTO @variableName ...`

Comment: @GermannArlington, an `int` is not a table variable.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
alter proc [dbo].[SpGetRelatedProducts](@pid int)
as

select *
from product as p1
where p1.subcate_id in (
                         select p2.subcate_id 
                         from product as p2
                         where p2.pid = @pid
                       )
```

Comment: thnk u vey much
its working now............-:)

Comment: of course, both this and my answer could give an incorrect results if rows with differeing `subcate_id` share a `pid`

Answer (score 1):

The `@subcate` parameter is not assigned:

```
select @subcate = subcate_id from product where pid=@pid

select * from product where product.subcate_id = @subcate
```

Answer (score 0):

Your may as well do this all in one statement

```
SELECT
               P1.* 
    FROM
             product P1
        JOIN
             prodcut P2
                 ON p1.subcate_id = p2.subcate_id
    WHERE
        P2.pid = @pid
```

and not worry about setting the intermediate variable.